# NodeJS Python-Shell output not working as wanted

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, node-modules

I am trying to set up a website where users can run some python code and the executing part of the code is working fine, the only problem is that python-shell waits for the code to be complete then send-outs the output. (See attached screenshots below)

What the current output looks like:

[image: What the current output looks like]

What I'm trying to achieve:

[image: What I'm trying to achieve]

Here is my config for Py-Shell:

```js
let {
  PythonShell
} = require('python-shell')

var run = 1;
pyshell: PythonShell
constructor(); {
  this.pyshell = new PythonShell(__dirname + "/physics.py")
  pythonPath: '/usr/bin/python3';
  pythonOptions: ['i', ]



  if (run == 1) {

    socket.on("hello", function(pyinput2) {

      var input = pyinput2
      console.log(input, "sending");
      this.pyshell.send(input)
      console.log(input, "sent")

    });


  }

  this.pyshell.on("message", (...args) => {
    console.log(args)
    socket.send(args)
    this.pyshell.end
  })

  this.pyshell.on('message', function(message) {
    // received a message sent from the Python script (a simple "print" statement)
    console.log(message + "\n");

  });
```

Here is the python script I'm using for testing:

```
# Program make a simple calculator

# This function adds two numbers
def add(x, y):
    return x + y

# This function subtracts two numbers
def subtract(x, y):
    return x - y

# This function multiplies two numbers
def multiply(x, y):
    return x * y

# This function divides two numbers
def divide(x, y):
    return x / y


print("Select operation.")
print("1.Add")
print("2.Subtract")
print("3.Multiply")
print("4.Divide")

while True:
    # take input from the user
    choice = input("Enter choice(1/2/3/4): ")

    # check if choice is one of the four options
    if choice in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
        num1 = float(input("Enter first number: "))
        num2 = float(input("Enter second number: "))

        if choice == '1':
            print(num1, "+", num2, "=", add(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '2':
            print(num1, "-", num2, "=", subtract(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '3':
            print(num1, "*", num2, "=", multiply(num1, num2))

        elif choice == '4':
            print(num1, "/", num2, "=", divide(num1, num2))
        
        # check if user wants another calculation
        # break the while loop if answer is no
        next_calculation = input("Let's do next calculation? (yes/no): ")
        if next_calculation == "no":
          break
    
    else:
        print("Invalid Input")
```

I'm new to javascript so sorry if I lack some knowledge... any help would be greatly appreciated - Thanks

Comment: Well, you log an array of arguments (`args`). It's an array because you specified `...`. If you only want the first argument to be printed, rather use a single argument like `str` instead of a rest operator. Or, if you want to, say, concatenate all arguments, you could use `args.join('')`.

Comment: @CherryDT When removing the `...` infront of (`args`) the same behavior occurs with the output